# Should I replace my applications' bundled Python directories with links to a single Python library?

Tags: windows, python, symbolic-link

Recently, I reinstalled Python on my Windows 10 PC, and after a minor issue (the installer didn't automatically add itself to my `PATH` for some reason, so I had to manually add it myself), I decided, on a whim, to search my filesystem looking for all Python installations. As you might expect, I found many, each bundled with a different program like Sublime Text or Inkscape.

My idea is to delete all Python 3 folders in these programs & replace them with symbolic links pointing to the Python 3 that I just installed, in order to save space. I assume that Python 3.8.2 (the latest version as of this post) has backwards compatibility with previous versions of Python 3, so this should allow the programs to run as they already have been.

Would this be good practice or not? (Also, if I uninstall any of these programs in the future, would the uninstaller not stop at symlinks & recursively delete everything in the shared Python library, ruining the other programs?)

Comment: While definitely an opinion, I would say the safe answer would be not to do this. Not specific to those programs, but not all programs come bundled with Python 3 (some may still use Python 2). Also, the assumption that each program may not use different and/or custom Python modules may be incorrect.

Comment: There are certain situations where this type of approach is definitely fine (e.g. ImageMagick and FFmpeg, where a system-wide FFmpeg installation generally invalidates the need for installing FFmpeg with ImageMagick ) but Python installations can vary enough that if you want to try this with a Python reliant application, you should probably think about simply renaming the "extraneous" Python installation folders, creating your ex. symlinks, and thoroughly testing the application before your remove anything.

Comment: All right, thanks for the replies. With the possibility of modified Python installations in mind, I've decided not to do this for now.